# How to get ctrl-click in VSCode on Mac to behave consistently for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, macos, visual-studio-code, widget

The problem: one one Mac, in VSCode, when I cntrl-click on a widget, the refactoring/wrapping menu comes up--the same menu that comes up when you press command + '.'. This is the correct behavior.

BUT on the other Mac, when I press cntrl-click on a widget, the 'go to definition' menu pops up. This is not desirable or correct.

What's different in the configuration that's resulting in different behavior and how can I change it?

Both machines are up to date with latest VScode and Flutter versions, as well as extensions.

Comment: Have you checked whether or not your environment is has **exactly the same** configurations and VSCode extensions? If you're unsure if the environments are the same, try using the [settings sync](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) feature of VSCode

Comment: Also additional information. Sometimes this is caused because of bad hardware. A slow device can sometimes cause for delays when showing the ctrl + click.

Comment: thanks for the responses! adding my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the way it works with VSCode and Flutter is a two step process, like this:

1. ctrl-click brings up the 'go to definition' etc menu. This is a VSCode popup. If you look down about halfway through, one of the items on the menu is 'refactor'.
2. click on refactor on this popup menu, and a menu pops up in a different text format. This is a Flutter popup, independent of the VSCode IDE. the 'wrap' functions are on this Flutter popup menu.

and as always, cmd + '.' does the same thing in one step.